# Class Custom __eq__ as Comparison of Hashes

Tags: python, class, hash, equality

Consider a custom class:

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.a, self.b))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__hash__() == other.__hash__()
```

Is it a bad idea to make equality reliant upon the hash?  This seems like a much more elegant and readable mechanism than checking each pair of attributes in a piecemeal fashion for larger numbers of attributes ala

```
self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b and ... self.n == other.n
```

or a more dynamic check using getattr and a list (is there a better way to compare large numbers of pairs of attributes?)

Is the size of the hash returned by the builtin hash function not large enough to be reliable in relatively large sets of data?

Comment: Try `MyObject(-1, 0) ==  MyObject(-2, 0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a bad idea. Hashes are not unique, objects with equal hashes are *not* guaranteed to actually be equal too:

```
>>> (-1, 0) == (-2, 0)
False
>>> hash((-1, 0)) == hash((-2, 0))
True
```

Hashes are not *meant* to be unique; they are a means to pick a slot in a limited-size [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) quickly, to facilitate O(1) dictionary look-ups, and collisions are *allowed and expected*.

Yes, Python requires that equal objects should have equal hashes, but that doesn't mean the relationship can be reversed.

I just compare tuples:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return (self.a, self.b) == (other.a, other.b)
```

If you are writing a lot of *data classes*, simple classes that all need equality testing and hashing, etc. use the [`dataclasses` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) (Python 3.7 or up, or use a [backport](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/)):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class MyObject:
    a: int
    b: int
```

The above class now comes with a `__hash__` and `__equals__` method:

```
>>> MyObject(-1, 0) == MyObject(-2, 0)
False
>>> hash(MyObject(-1, 0)) == hash(MyObject(-2, 0))
True
>>> MyObject(42, 12345) == MyObject(42, 12345)
True
```

Comment: You say you compare tuples, but is there any reason not to do `return vars(self) == vars(other)`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey: I prefer being explicit; `vars(self) == vars(other)` breaks the moment you store some additional attributes on the objects (annotations for a different use case, say). `obj._cache_key = 'foobar'` breaking equality testing would be very surprising.